# Can I send a command from Linux to host Windows (WSL)?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am working high accuracy of timers in Windows. But timers in Windows are not accurate. Therefore, I have installed Windows Subsystem for Linux version 2(WSL) which is maybe not a solution for my application. I have seen many resources and videos regarding file sharing between them. My question is that is it possible to use Linux high accuracy timers in WSL. Another words, I would like to send command from Linux to Windows to execute task more precisely. It is a new concept, I hope there is already this kind of feature. The more specific example is that a program sends a command to output of industrial PC by TCP communication, the program must work in Windows however, I would like to use Linux because of the accuracy of the timer. Is there any article about this connection or any information? Because I have not found yet.